# Reverse geocoding doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I'm writing a small web page and one of my functionalities is to take a photo and write the location (street and city) instantly on the taken photo.
Here's my code:

```
window.cb = function  cb(json) {
            document.getElementById('city').value = json.address.road+ " " + json.address.postcode + ',' + json.address.city;
}

window.search =  function search(x,y) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');       
    s.src = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=cb&format=json&lat=' + x + '&lon=' + y + '&addressdetails=1&accept-language=en-US';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

};

....

search(x,y); 
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    context.strokeText(city, 270, 260);
    }, 2000);
```

It works fine on the desktop version, but fails when tried on mobile device. I tried setting the timeout to higher value - doesn't help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console when you execute your code on mobile? Also, can you share with us the HTML?

Comment: So, I found the mistake. I was sending http request(```'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org...```), but my mobile browser required https...funny I didn't think about that. Thanks though